# Echo Option Value Based On Wordpress User Role

Tags: php, user-roles, options, select

If someone can figure this out, man you would make my week!

Basically what I'm trying to do is echo a different value in a option based on a the users role on Wordpress.

If user is administrator echo = user@email.com If user is subscriber echo = admin@email.com

Here is the code I am working with:

```
if ( ! empty( $note_emails ) || $include_custom ) { ?>
    <div class="gv-note-email-container">
        <label for="gv-note-email-to-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo $strings['also-email'];  ?></label>
        <select class="gv-note-email-to" name="gv-note-to" id="gv-note-email-to-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>">
            <?php foreach ( $note_emails as  $email ) {
                ?>
                <option value="admin@email.com">admin@email.com</option>
            <?php }
            if( $include_custom ) { ?>
            <option value="custom"><?php echo self::strings('other-email'); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <fieldset class="gv-note-to-container">
            <?php if( $include_custom ) { ?>
            <div class='gv-note-to-custom-container'>
                <label for="gv-note-email-to-custom-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>"><?php echo $strings['email-label']; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="gv-note-to-custom" placeholder="<?php echo $strings['email-placeholder']; ?>" id="gv-note-to-custom-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" value="" />
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class='gv-note-subject-container'>
                <label for="gv-note-subject-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>"><?php echo $strings['subject-label']; ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="gv-note-subject" placeholder="<?php echo $strings['subject']; ?>" id="gv-note-subject-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: where do you use this code ?

Comment: I am modifying a php file inside the plugin Gravity View

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  if(current_user_can('administrator')){
    echo '<option value="user@email.com">user@email.com</option>';
  }elseif(current_user_can('subscriber')){
    echo '<option value="admin@email.com">admin@email.com</option>';
  }
```

Maybe this should be wrapped in a user logged in check like this:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  if(current_user_can('administrator')){
    echo '<option value="user@email.com">user@email.com</option>';
  }elseif(current_user_can('subscriber')){
    echo '<option value="admin@email.com">admin@email.com</option>';
  }
}
```